# Problem in Binary Search Tree Implementation

Tags: c, binary-search-tree, implementation

I am pretty much new to the structs in C. I tried to implement a binary search tree but failed.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct tree{
    int data;
    struct tree *left;
    struct tree *right;
};

struct tree *root = NULL;

void add(int value, struct tree *temp){
    if(temp==NULL){
        temp = (struct tree *) malloc(sizeof(struct tree));
        temp->left=NULL;
        temp->right=NULL;
        temp->data=value;
        return;
    }
    else{
        if((value) > (temp->data)){
            add(value, temp->right);
        }else{
            add(value, temp->left);
        }
    }
}

void printTree(struct tree *temp){
    if (temp != NULL) {
        printTree(temp->left);
        printf("%d ", temp->data);
        printTree(temp->right);
    }
}

int main(){
    add(4, root);
    add(2, root);
    add(3, root);
    add(1, root);
    add(6, root);
    add(7, root);
    add(5, root);
    printTree(root);
}
```

I think I cannot make the connections between addresses in the right way but I couldn't figure out how to solve it.

Comment: Please describe in more detail what `failed` means.

Comment: Your `root` will always be `null`. When you assign to `temp = malloc(...)`, you're editing that local `temp` variable, which is totally unrelated to the `root` variable from which it once got its initial value when the function was called. More generally, this `add` API has a bit of a sharp edge. It would be better to have a seperate `tree_create()` function (or whatever) which returns a new tree with no nodes, and call `tree_add()` with that new tree. As written, any call to `add` with an accidentally null pointer will allocate a new tree, which is quite unexpected

Comment: Never just describe a problem as “failed.” When asking for help with a program, state what the program does (what the observed behavior is) and what you want it to do (what the desired behavior is). If it is not clear, explain the difference between the observed behavior and the desired behavior. Also reduce the problem to the smallest case that shows a problem. Provide a [mre]. For example, you only need one `add` call to demonstrate a bug in which a tree is not printed.

Comment: @Alexander thanks for your suggestion. I solved it by defining another temp node in addition section and returning it. I also edited the `add(x,root)` as `root= add(x,root)` in `main()`